# I can not get result from AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, mysql, multithreading, android-asynctask

Is this code true .I am using from AsyncTask for get result but cant not see any result and i am using WampServer. I think that my error logical is in my `getter/setter` :

```
public class NotesActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                WebPageTask task = new WebPageTask();
                task.execute(new String[] { "http://192.168.5.170:8081/note-server/" });
    }

    private class WebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ArrayList<StructTask> nettasks = new ArrayList<StructTask>();
            JSONObject object = null;
            JSONArray tasks = null;
            StructTask task = new StructTask();
            try {
             tasks = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {
                    object = tasks.getJSONObject(i);

                    task.setid(object.getLong("task_id"));
                    task.settitle(object.getString("task_title"));
                    task.setdesc(object.getString("task_desc"));
                    task.settone(object.getBoolean("task_done"));
                    nettasks.add(task);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("LOG","dd");
            for (StructTask taskesss : nettasks) {
                Log.i("LOG", "Taskes: " + taskesss.getid()+"|"+taskesss.gettitle()+"|"+taskesss.getdesc() + "-" + taskesss.getdone());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And this is `Getter/Setter` in `StructTask.java`. I think that i have logical error in my `class getter/setter` :

```
public class StructTask {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String desc;
    private boolean done;

    public long getid() {
        return this.id;
    }

    void setid(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String gettitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    void settitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getdesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    void setdesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public boolean getdone() {
        return this.done;
    }

    void setdone(boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }
}
```

Bellow code dont return any results :

```
    for (StructTask taskesss : nettasks) {
        Log.i("LOG", "Taskes: " + taskesss.getid()+"|"+taskesss.gettitle()+"|"+taskesss.getdesc() + "-" + taskesss.getdone());
    }
```

This is my sql page :
[image: THIS ONE]
[image: AND THIS ONE]

Comment: What kind of error is it? Where do you get it?

Comment: [Debug?](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html) [LogCat?](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

Comment: can you able to get URL in your android browse ??

Comment: what is the value  log.i and are  the values set correctly ?

Comment: Yes i can get URL and etc.. . I know that my Logical error is in :task.setid(object.getLong("task_id"));
                    task.settitle(object.getString("task_title"));
                    task.setdesc(object.getString("task_desc"));
                    task.settone(object.getBoolean("task_done"));
                    nettasks.add(task);

Comment: first check if you are parsing your json correctly and then check what values are set to variables

Comment: It should return for me (for example) : 0 | Book | Story | false ---- 1 | Pen | Note | true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is true . but :

1- in your `getter/setter` Class :

```
private boolean done;
public boolean getdone() {
    return this.done;
}

void setdone(boolean done) {
    this.done = done;
}
```

Change to :

```
private int done;
public int getdone() {
    return this.done;
}

void setdone(int done) {
    this.done = done;
}
```

2- And change to :

.....your codes...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ArrayList<StructTask> nettasks = new ArrayList<StructTask>();
    try {
        JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = tasks.getJSONObject(i);
            StructTask task = new StructTask();
            task.setid(object.getLong("task_id"));
            task.settitle(object.getString("task_title"));
            task.setdesc(object.getString("task_desc"));
            task.setdone(object.getInt("task_done"));
            nettasks.add(task);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

...your codes...

3- And connect to your pc and android with `Thethering & Wi-Fi hotspot` this option is in your `setting` mobile and then by Wi-Fi pc connect to your mobile . Now you can see your favorit result.

GOOD LOOK